# Data changes for no reason in angular injectable service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular16, dataservice

I have a service that contains a list of dateRanges. A dateRange contains a start and endDate. I have two places where I use inject this service and want to use the list. This is my service that contains the data:

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DateRange } from 'src/app/models/dateRange';

@Injectable()
export class AvailabilityService {
  private readonly fullDateRanges: DateRange[];

  private readonly fullDates: Date[] =[
    new Date("2023-11-10")
  ]

constructor() {
  this.fullDateRanges = [
    new DateRange("2023-11-17", "2023-11-20"),
    new DateRange("2023-12-15", "2023-12-18"),
    new DateRange("2023-12-30", "2024-01-01"),
    new DateRange("2024-02-12", "2024-02-16"),
    new DateRange("2024-07-13", "2024-07-19"),
    new DateRange("2024-07-13", "2024-07-19"),
    new DateRange("2024-07-24", "2024-08-05"),
    new DateRange("2024-03-14", "2024-03-23"),
    new DateRange("2024-10-31", "2024-11-09"),
  ]
}

public GetFullDatesRangesForAllDates(): DateRange[]{
  var allFullDatesRanges: DateRange[] = this.fullDateRanges;

  this.fullDates.forEach((date: Date) => {
    var dateString: string = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate().toString();
    allFullDatesRanges.push(new DateRange(dateString, dateString))
  });

  allFullDatesRanges.sort((a: DateRange, b: DateRange) => {
    return a.startDate.getTime() - b.startDate.getTime();
  });

 return allFullDatesRanges;
}

  public GetAllFullDates(): Date[]{
    var dates: Date[] = [];

    this.fullDateRanges.forEach((dateRange: DateRange) => {
      var allDatesFromRange: Date[] = this.getDatesFromRange(dateRange)

        allDatesFromRange.forEach((date: Date) => {
        dates.push(date);
      })
    });

    this.fullDates.forEach((date: Date) => {
      dates.push(date);
    })

    return dates;
  }

  private getDatesFromRange(dateRange: DateRange): Date[]{
    var dates: Date[] = [];

    var currentDate: Date = dateRange.startDate;
    while(currentDate <= dateRange.endDate){
      dates.push(new Date(currentDate));
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return dates;
  }
}
```

I use this service inside this component:

```
public fullDateRanges: DateRange[];
public displayedColumns: string[] = ['startDate', 'endDate'];
public readableFullDateRanges: ReadableDateRangeFormat[] = [];

  constructor(availabilityService: AvailabilityService){
    this.fullDateRanges = availabilityService.GetFullDatesRangesForAllDates();
    this.getReadableDateStrings();
  }

  private getReadableDateStrings(): void{
    this.fullDateRanges.forEach((dateRange: DateRange) => {
      var startDate: string = dateRange.startDate.getDate().toString()  + "-" + (dateRange.startDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + dateRange.startDate.getFullYear().toString();
      var endDate: string = dateRange.endDate.getDate().toString()  + "-" + (dateRange.endDate.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + dateRange.endDate.getFullYear().toString();
      var readableDate: ReadableDateRangeFormat = new ReadableDateRangeFormat();
      readableDate.startDate = startDate;
      readableDate.endDate = endDate;
      this.readableFullDateRanges.push(readableDate);
    });
  }
}
```

HTML of that component:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <div class="heading_container margin_bottom">
          <h4>Hier staan alle datums die wij gesloten of volgeboekt zijn</h4>
        </div>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="readableFullDateRanges" class="mat-elevation-z8">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Begin datum</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.startDate }}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="endDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Eind datum</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.endDate }}</td>
          </ng-container>
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I go to the page with this component then I see this:
[image: correct data in table]

and that is correct, but if navigate to this component via my other page:

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, protected availabilityService: AvailabilityService) {
    this.dogBirthMaxDate = new Date();
    this.fullDates = availabilityService.GetAllFullDates();
  }
```

HTML

```
          <div class="mat-form-field-additional-info"> Alle niet aanklikbare datums zijn vol of niet meer beschikbaar</div>
          <div class="mat-form-field-additional-info"> Kijk hier voor alle <a routerLink="/volle-datums"routerLinkActive="active" 
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
              volle datums
            </a></div>
            <mat-form-field class="margin_bottom">
              <mat-label>Wanneer gaat uw hond op vakantie?</mat-label>
              <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="comeAndGetDatePicker" [min]="comeMinDate" [dateFilter]="reservationDateFilter">
                <input matStartDate placeholder="DD/MM/JJJJ" formControlName="comeDate" />
                <input matEndDate placeholder="DD/MM/JJJJ" formControlName="getDate" />
              </mat-date-range-input>
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="comeAndGetDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-date-range-picker #comeAndGetDatePicker></mat-date-range-picker>
              <mat-error *ngIf="comeDate.errors?.['required']">Een datum is verplicht.</mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="getDate.errors?.['required'] && !comeDate.errors?.['required']">Een ophaal datum is verplicht.</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Then for some reason my data in the service where the data comes from is randomly changed:
[image: screenshot changed data]

All the startDates are changed to the endDate and the endDate are changed to the startDates wwhat results in:
[image: wrong dates in table]
I don't know why this is happening, please can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't go deep into right now, but here `  var allFullDatesRanges: DateRange[] = this.fullDateRanges;` you are assigning a reference to the same variable that will be mutated and re-used in the constructor. Meaning that initializing things twice could be resulting in some unexpected.

Comment: @CaioOliveira this the code from: var allFullDatesRanges: DateRange[] = this.fullDateRanges;
to: var allFullDatesRanges: DateRange[] = [];

  this.fullDateRanges.forEach(element => {
    allFullDatesRanges.push(element);
  });
So I don't have that reference anymore
But this I get still weird behavior.
Thnx for your response mate! Really thankfull for that

Comment: you shouldn't use `var`. stick with `let` or `const`.  Besides Caio's comment, you should use `Observables` for handling data and sharing on your services

Comment: @pieterjanse freeze your date range objects and you will get an exception when they are mutated. This exception will show you what part of your (or external library) code messes up the data.

Comment: this.fullDateRanges = Object.freeze([
    new DateRange("2023-11-17", "2023-11-20"),
    new DateRange("2023-12-15", "2023-12-18"),
    new DateRange("2023-12-30", "2024-01-01"),
    new DateRange("2024-02-12", "2024-02-16"),
    new DateRange("2024-07-13", "2024-07-19"),
    new DateRange("2024-07-13", "2024-07-19"),
    new DateRange("2024-07-24", "2024-08-05"),
    new DateRange("2024-03-14", "2024-03-23"),
    new DateRange("2024-10-31", "2024-11-09"),
  ]);
}
I freezed the object with this code, but I don't get an exception and still my data has changed.

Comment: But I think I don't get an exception because freeze does a shallow copy on objects

Comment: @Andres2142 why should I use obserables here?